# Adding more information when JUnit 4 timeouts with parameterized runner

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, junit4, parameterized-unit-test

I am running a JUnit 4 test using `@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)`. This works fine, no problems there. However, when any of my 34 tests timeout, I only get the message `java.lang.Exception: test timed out after 15000 milliseconds`. I want it to also show the parameter of the test.

I have even tried to do it like the code below (which I know is a horrible solution for most cases, I just wanted to see if I could get the message to show any time at all), but that did not work, it still resulted in the message above.

```
private String parameter;

@Test(timeout = 15000)
public void solveAll() {
    try {
        // ... do something that might take a long time
    }
    catch (Throwable e) {
        Assert.fail(this.parameter + " failed! Because of " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

How can I make JUnit also show `this.parameter` when the test results in a timeout ?

Here is a very simple example test class that shows this problem:

```
public class ShowMyMessageTest {
    @Test(timeout=1000)
    public void test() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
            Assert.fail("Timeout reached with value 42");
        }
    }
}
```

With this `ShowMyMessageTest` I sometimes get the expected "Timeout reached with value 42", and sometimes I get only "java.lang.Exception: test timed out after 1000 milliseconds". I want to always get "Timeout reached with value 42" in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but you could use [@After](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/After.html) to check the state of the parameter:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class) public class FooTest {
  private boolean flag = true;
  private String param;

  public FooTest(String param) {
    this.param = param;
  }

  @Test(timeout = 1000) public void test() {
    while(true == flag);
    param = null;
  }

  @After public void after() {
    Assert.assertNull("Problem:" + param, param);
  }

  @Parameters public static Collection<Object[]> params() {
    Object[][] params = { { "foo" } };
    return Arrays.asList(params);
  }
}
```

An alternative is to write your own [runner](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/runners/package-summary.html).